# How can I tweak this Javascript code to print all permutations of sentences on each line of input?

Tags: javascript, string, loops

So for example if I have this input:

```
I am the man
```

I wanna get back:

```
I am the man
I the man
I man
I the
I am
am the man
am man
am the
the man
man
man I
man I am
etc.
```

This is what I have so far for the first 20 sentences of input

```
            for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                var currWords = data[i].DisplayName.replace(/[^\x00-\x7F]/g, "").replace(/\(/g, "").replace(/\-/g, " ").replace(/\)/g, "").replace(/\*/g, "").toLowerCase().split(/\s+/g);

                for (var j = 0; j < currWords.length; j++) {
                    var currString = "";
                    for (var k = j; k < currWords.length; k++) {
                        currString += (currWords[k] + " ");
                    }
                    console.log(currString);
                }
            }
```

I just want these printed so I can copy them for something else. So far it is only doing things forwards, and I cant think of an easy way to make it do every possible sentence. What do you recomend?

Comment: Do you wanna a specific order ?

Comment: Nope. Just all possibilities

Comment: Those are not permutations of your sentence, they're the permutations of all subsets.

Comment: My bad. Should've said that.

Comment: The problem of permutations has been studied to death. Consult any book on algorithms, or just search the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a look at your Question i think you can adapt 
[Heap´s algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap%27s_algorithm)

i write and adapt this to es6 with the only change, that
i build the string with bitCheck operators...

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>I am the man</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="output"></div>
  <script>
    p = m => {
      var a = m.split(' '),
      s = new Set(), l = a.length, ms, 
      b = (n=l) => {
        if (n == 1) {
          for ( let i = 1; i < 2**l; i++){
            ms = '';
            for ( let y = 0; y < l; y++){
              if (i & (1 << y)){
                ms += a[y]+" ";
              }
            }
          s.add(ms.trim());
          }
      } 
        else {
          for (let i=0;i<n;i++) {
            b(n - 1);
            [a[(n%2)*i],a[n-1]] = [a[n-1],a[(n%2)*i]];
          }
        }
      }
      b();
      return s;
    }
    test = p("I am the man")
    test.forEach(e => output.innerHTML += e + '<br>');
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. This was more so what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Well, Its the question about creating the permutation, can be a generic question as well, instead of javascript specific, or sentence specific, there can be multiple approaches, let ma explain one of them what I can think currently in short term:

SO, your sentence  "I am the man" having four words, what about first split them to a array like

```
var words = "I am the man".split(" ")
```

so your array have the words `["I", "am", "the", "man"]` and `length` is `4` because you have 4 words.
Now, what about producing the permutation of these numbers (`1234`) and use each result's each digit as the index of word array and join? confused? Let me explain.

What if we can produce a array like

`[1, 2, 3, 4, 12, 13, 14, 21, 23, 24, 41, 42, 43, 123, 124, ...., 4321]`

and then from each number you can construct a sentence:

eg:

```
1: "I"
4: "man"
43: "man the"
..
..
4321: "man the am I"
```

(If you have question on this how to generate this strings from the numbers, I will clarify that later, for now don't forget you already have the array of words)

Now, the question might occur what if we are calculating permutation of more that `9` entry? For `9` the max value would be `987654321` (as we are thinking everything as number), so in all the cases I prefer to construct an array instead of numbers, because ultimately we need to split all the numbers and fetch from index from word array,

so, in instead of

`[1, 2, 3, 4, 12, 13, 14, 21, 23, 24, 41, 42, 43, 123, 124, ...., 4321]`

I will prefer

`[ [1], [2], [3], [4], [1, 2], [1, 3],..., [3, 4, 1],........., [4, 3, 2, 1] ]`

because number can go beyond `9` and we can handle that easily.

So, now the question is how you will construct the array of numbers (believe me, that is the ultimate thing to do, your output is just a logical map on it)

So if we start with a array by initializing it like: `[[1], [2], [3], [4]]` upto length, so we will start with level 2,

we will loop, 1 to Length (i.e. 1 to 4) and in each iteration we will iterate to each array and will check the the array is containing the current number or not, if not we will slice the array, and push the current number at beginning and then push it back to main result array. we will also pass the each digit array so that we don't need to look into the entire array, for level 1, both will be the same so we will make a copy of it by `slice()`, and we will return an array also for current digit

```
function processEachDigit(length, mainArray, lastDigitArray) {
    var currDigitArray = [];
    var n;
    for (n = 1; n <= length; n++) {
        for (idx = 0; idx < lastDigitArray.length; idx++) {
            var eachArray = lastDigitArray[idx];
            if (!eachArray.includes(n)) {
                var newArr = eachArray.slice();
                newArr.unshift(n)
                mainArray.push(newArr);
                currDigitArray.push(newArr)
            }
        }
    }
return currDigitArray;
}
```

so for the first time we have

`mainArray = [[1], [2], [3], [4]] //will initialize through a loop`

and

```
currDigitArray  = mainArray.slice()
//as we will keep update mainArray we cannot use the same reference
```

and we will call it like

```
processEachDigit(words.length, mainArray, currDigitArray)
```

so the mainArray was

`[[1], [2], [3], [4]]`

and it became

`[[1], [2], [3], [4], [1, 2], [1,3], ......., [4,2], [4,3]]`

and it returns the array of second digit element, i.e.

`[[1,2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 1], [2, 3]......., [4,2], [4,3]]`

so we will call with second digit array to construct the 3rd digit array, and then pass the 3rd digit array to construct the 4th digit array.

Now, do we really need to construct the single digit array initially? NO.

passing an empty array of array will create it as no element will be found there, so we are all set just need to initialize the main array as empty array and current digit array as empty array of array, I just told `slice()` and all to explain what we are trying to do.

here we go

```
function getPermutationArray(L) {
var mainArr = [];
var n;
var currDigitArr = [[]];
    for(n=1;n<=L;n++) {
        currDigitArr = processEachDigit(L, mainArr, currDigitArr);
    }
return mainArr;
}
```

now you can call `getPermutationArray(<any number>)`with any number and that will return you the array, now try to map from that array. in case you fail, I will help you, that's a easy job.

**Note:** *I could have written a small code segment, but just wrote so many things to explain it properly, and also there might be so many approaches, just tried one of them as I don't want to go for recursion, using recursion also we can achieve this. comment if anything is not clear.*

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Thank you, after working through this I have decided to make a different plan. This method showed me how many possible permutations would be created. For 700 lines that I need, it would create nearly half a million. Yikes.